# Does probability depend on order?

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a playlist of 20 tracks ordered by artist name. The songs' titles don't matter.

```
1) Rihanna
2) Rihanna
3) Rihanna
4) Rihanna

5) Moby
6) Moby
7) Moby
8) Moby

9) Rammstein
10) Rammstein
11) Rammstein
12) Rammstein

13) Eminem
14) Eminem
15) Eminem
16) Eminem

17) Beyonce
18) Beyonce
19) Beyonce
20) Beyonce
```

And then I shuffle that playlist. So now it's like:

```
1) Moby
2) Rihanna
3) Beyonce
4) Rihanna
5) Eminem
6) Rammstein
7) Beyonce
8) Rihanna
9) Rammstein
10) Rammstein
11) Eminem
12) Moby
13) Moby
14) Eminem
15) Rammstein
16) Eminem
17) Moby
18) Beyonce
19) Rihanna
20) Beyonce
```

And the question is: in which case I have more chances to play 2 or 3 Moby's track in a row if I would randomly pick a track form a list? In other words: does shuffling a shuffled list gives you more chances to get 2 or more items of a same kind?

Comment: There's no difference between a random selection and a permutation followed by a random selection.

Comment: If you shuffling a shuffled list changes some chances that means the first shuffling was not good enough!